# Rails: Creating form fields for join-table dependent on own model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, has-many-through

I'm trying to build a form for a model with a join-table containing references to itself.
I'll give you a quick example of what i'm trying to achive:

Lets say i have the subject physics. To learn physics you will need to know basic math, i.e physics is dependent on math. Any subject should be able to have multiple dependencies both ways.
What i'm having problems with is submitting this relationship through a form.

My code:

Model:

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :needs, foreign_key: :target_id
    has_many :subjects, through: :needs

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :needs,:subjects,allow_destroy: true
end
class Need < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :target, class_name: :subject
    belongs_to :prerequisite, class_name: :subject
end
```

Controller:

```
class SubjectsController < ApplicationController
def create
  @subject = Subject.new secure_params
  if @subject.save
    redirect_to root_path, success: 'Subject created'
  else
    render :new
  end
end

def new
  @subject = Subject.new
end

private

def secure_params
  params.require(:subject).permit(:name, :content, needs_attributes: [:target,:prerequisite])
  end
end
```

Form:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-8">
   <%= simple_nested_form_for @subject do |f| %>
       <%= f.input :name %>
       <%= f.input :content %>

       <%= f.fields_for :needs do |d| %>
           <%=d.association :prerequisite %>
       <% end %>
       <%= f.link_to_add "Add a prerequisite", :needs %>

       <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' %>
   <% end %>
 </div>
</div>
```

Using this approach i get "uninitialized constant Need::subject" on entering the "new" action. 
Any ideas on mistakes in my approach or code will be greatly appreciated.
Edit: adding join table

```
class CreateNeeds < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :needs do |t|

      t.references :target
      t.references :prerequisite
    end
  end
end
```

Edit2: working code (only changed parts)

Model

```
 class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :needs, foreign_key: :target_id
    has_many :prerequisites, class_name: "Subject",through: :needs, source: :prerequisites

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :needs,:prerequisites,allow_destroy: true
end
class Need < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :target, class_name: "Subject"
    belongs_to :prerequisite, class_name: "Subject"
end
```

Controller

```
   def secure_params
  params.require(:subject).permit(:name, :content, needs_attributes: [:prerequisite_id])
  end
end
```

Comment: What are the db fields in your Need join table?  Also, before you start doing forms, do all of your associations work in the console?  Eg can you say `subject1 = Subject.first; subject2 = Subject.last; subject1.subjects << subject2` and `subject1 = Subject.first;  need = Need.new; need.target = subject1;need.save`, etc?

Comment: Adding the join table in original post. need.target does indeed not work, and gives the same error, any suspicion as to why?

Comment: sidenote: need.target_id =subject1.id does work, and i've solved this temporarily by creating the needs in the controller after the subject is saved, but i'm hoping there's a more elegant way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like i said in my comment, focus on making sure all the associations are hooked up properly before you worry about forms.  The console, or automated tests, are both a good place to test this.

I think it maybe should be like so:

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :needs,  as: :target
  has_many :subjects, :class_name: "Subject",  through: :needs, source: :prerequisite

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :needs,:subjects,allow_destroy: true
end

#assuming you have fields target_id and prerequisite_id in this table
class Need < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :target, class_name: :subject
  belongs_to :prerequisite, class_name: :subject
end
```

I think the association name "subjects" is potentially confusing as it will return the subjects that *this* subject requires.  This isn't immediately obvious to the reader, which could include you in the future.

At some point you may want to list the subjects that *require* this subject.  It may be worth differentiating between these now, so you can clearly tell the difference.  You could do this like so:

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :required_needs,  as: :target
  has_many :required_by_needs,  as: :prerequisite

  has_many :required_subjects, :class_name: "Subject",  through: :required_needs, source: :prerequisite
  has_many :required_by_subjects, :class_name: "Subject",  through: :required_by_needs, source: :target

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :required_needs, :required_by_needs, :required_subjects, :required_by_subjects, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem seems to be that i misunderstood the ":subjects" part as a reference to the class rather than an association name. I'll update the post with a fixed version if anyone is interested.